# Passing variables from ruby file to a node.js script

Tags: ruby, node.js, variables, bots, sharing

Was looking at gon and gon-sinatra and attempted to use them, but to no avail. Seems like it's for javascript files and not node.js files, if anyone could help it would be much appreciated!

Command.rb

```
        #!/usr/bin/ruby
        require 'bitcoin-client'
        require 'net/http'
        require 'sinatra'
        require 'json'
        require 'gon-sinatra'
        Sinatra::register Gon::Sinatra

   class MySinatraApplication < Sinatra::Base
          register Gon::Sinatra

    @price = `ruby fiat.rb `
    gon.price = @price

    end
```

Variable.js

```
alert(gon.price)
```

Error: Cannot find module 'gon-sinatra' from node.js file.

Comment: Have you considered writing a server or using a file?

Comment: I've attempted,  <%= include_gon %> is the go to for applying gon in your .js file. Something to do with an views/application.erb which does not exist. I'm new to .js.

Comment: Looks like you're new to programming. Welcome! People are reluctant to help if you don't show what you have tried, if you write about what you've tried and why it isn't working, that can make it much easier for the volunteers here to intelligently comment on your issue.

Comment: Edited the main question , yeah sorry I should of added the code. I got another error saying gon.method was not defined in ruby with just using gon.

Comment: Hey Sam, no worries. It's not possible to directly use Ruby code from Node.js (and vice versa). A really popular way to do this sort of thing is to write what is called an "API" or "Web Service". You can check this out online but it is pretty simple. If you are using sinatra, all you have to do is make a URL where you put `gon.price` inside a JSON response and write a Node.JS client to connect to it (either using `require('net')` or `fetch()`).

Comment: Sweet i'll have a shot tonight and let you know it goes!